# pass specific parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I have a function:

```
getBooks(page, count, authorId){
      return API.get('/books/?page=' +page + '&count='+count+ '&author='+ authorId})
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        })
}
```

I am implementing search function and in search I pass only the `authorId`  i.e

`getBooks(akdjh23)`

But on doing this it sets `akdjh23` to `page`. i.e `page=akdjh23` but I want `authorId=akdjh23`

My question is how do I send only `authorId` during search and `page` and `count` on general get request.

**Search based on id:**

```
getBooks(id)
```

**Get all books:**

```
get(1, 40) -> page=1, count=40
```

Comment: you cannot modify `getBooks`?

Comment: why `}` after `authorId}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getBooks(null, null, id)
```

should do the trick. Note that your code won't work as page and count in your function will not be defined.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an object rather the fixed parameters and destructure it by using `ES6 Object destructuring`

Example.

```
getBooks({ page, count, authorId }){
  return API.get('/books/?page=' +page + '&count='+count+ '&author='+ authorId})
    .then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

getBooks({ authorId: 45});
getBooks({ page: 'abc', authorId: 67});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple arguments you can change how getBooks work and pass an object instead

```
getBooks({ page, count, authorId })
```

you can now just pass the authorId if you need

```
getBooks({ authorId: 'authorIdPassed' });
```